# V-autocomplete @blur no value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to get the value of the selected values in a v-autocomplete when the blur event is triggerd. The value `$event.target.value` is always set to an empty string. I found a workaround by splitting the parentElement's innerText as such:

```js
var value = $event.parentElement.innerText;
value = value ? value.split('\n') : [];
```

It is worth noting that this only happens when I set the multiple prop in v-autocomplete:

```xml
<template v-slot:item.fieldName="{ item }">
  <v-autocomplete
    multiple
    small-chips
    :value="item.fieldName"
    :items="items"
    color="primary"
    @blur="updateItem(item, $event.target.value, 'fieldName')">
  </v-autocomplete>
</template>
```

I could not find anything concerning this issue. Am I not supposed to use this input this way ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using it with a **v-model**? Two-way binding should be used here so we will not need to manually get the items using $event.target.value.

```
<v-autocomplete
            v-model="values"
            :items="items"
            dense
            chips
            small-chips
            label="Solo"
            multiple
            solo
          ></v-autocomplete>
```

So you should be able to get the data directly from the **values** field. For reference:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/v-autocomplete/prop-dense.vue

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not viable since after each change the callback makes a call to the back end API to validate the input which in turn updates the state locally. So it is primordial that the callback is triggered only once after the user is done making changes.

Comment: When are you calling the api can you please share an example. And maybe try using debounce or send the API call on @input event?

Comment: The api is called inside the updateItem method.
`@blur="updateItem(item, $event.target.value, 'fieldName')"`